# c# wpf отображаемый цвет не совсем такой как нужен

Tags: c#, wpf, color

я в c# WPF отображаю на элементе Image текст определённого цвета - используя FormattedText.
FormattedText рисую на drawingContext.

```
var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
drawingContext.DrawText(new FormattedText(
                text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Consolas"), 18.0, (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#569cd6")))
, new Point(x, y));

...
targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(cWidth, cHeight, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Default);
targetBitmap.Render(visual);
```

и в итоге цвет результат не совпадает с желаемым .. вот на картинке - слева цвет какой должен выйти, а справа то что получается.
я так понимаю это или из-за того что используется Srgb , или потому что в wpf есть полупиксели?
как решить эту проблему?

**UPDATE:**
может ещё проблема в том что используется размытие grayscale , а в правильном варианте cleartype?если да, то как включить, пробовал включить для всего окна - никакого эффекта не дало

**UPDATE2:**
добавления в formattedtext - NumberSubstitution(),TextFormattingMode.Display
сделало его четче, но различия всё равно есть

```
new FormattedText(
                text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Consolas"), 18, color,new 
NumberSubstitution(),TextFormattingMode.Display)
```

[image: пример]

Comment: Не вижу разницы в цвете. И зачем рисовать на битмапе, если можно просто перекрасить текст в текстблоке? Или это особое извращение, которое мне не понять? )

Comment: @aepot разница есть, видно когда приблизить, ну или если шрифт больше сделать, в общем слева текст более чёткий, а справа более размытый. мне надо именно рисовать на image, поэтому и битмап

Comment: @aepot кроме размытости - слева используется cleartype, справа его нету, я не знаю как его для моего варианта включить

Comment: Так значит не в цвете проблема, а в сглаживании шрифта? Кстати, что за шрифт? Не вижу, где вы его задаете.

Comment: @aepot обновил вопрос, с учётом вашего примечания - вот какой шрифт new Typeface("consolas")
понятно что корень проблемы может "быть в чём угодно" , но результат проблемы - не правильный цвет

Comment: Не знаю на что это может повлиять, но `Consolas` пишется с большой буквы.

Comment: @aepot сделал так как вы предложили и не поменялось ровным счётом нечего, замечу что я так же поставил другой шрифт (Arial) и шрифт поменялся но проблема с цветом не исчезла. Там регистр не важен

Comment: Эээ, почему не `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x56, 0x9c, 0xd6))`?

Comment: Попробуйте `new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Consolas"), 18.0, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x56, 0x9c, 0xd6)), new NumberSubstitution(), TextFormattingMode.Display, 96.0)`

Comment: @VladD я изначально задавал цвет в виде rgb , в виде hex кода я привёл пока искал в интернете решение ..

Comment: @VladD TextFormattingMode.Display - сделало четче, но всё равно не так хорошо как с ClearType